# Can I remove doublet running program-button in Lubuntu panel?

Tags: lubuntu, panel

I use Lubuntu, it works good. But one thing is strange. I don't know how it happened but I get doublets "buttons" in the panel (in the bottom) for each program I run. I.e. two Firefox "buttons", two Terminal "buttons", two Geany "buttons"... they are "clones".

Can it be made to normal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had both

- *Application Launch* and
- *Task Bar*

in *Panel Applets*.

So of course it was my mistake.